# How to return a subclass of parameterized return type whose parametric type is a subclass of the return type's parametric type?

Tags: java, generics, java-6, parameterized-types

The title sounds a bit complicated, but in fact the question is quite simple.
I have the following method:

```
AbstractClassA<AbstractClassB> myMethod() {...}
```

And I want to invoke it like this:

```
ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl> result = myMethod();
```

The problem is that no matter what I tried, I ended up with [unchecked cast](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.2) warning or compiler error.

What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: What do you mean by "you want to invoke it like this"? The method has a certain return type. And you can't change this type. It may return an instance of `MyOtherClassAImpl<ClassBImpl>` - how should this be converted into a `ClassAImple<ClassBImpl>`? Or to put it that way: Which part of your code should be modified in order to achieve your goal? You could declare the method as `public <S extends AbstractClassB, T extends AbstractClassA<? extends S>> T myMethod()`, but this won't help you much, I guess...

Comment: But just as a method can declare to return `List` and has the right to return `ArrayList`, why can't my method do the above? I declare to return `X<Y>`, why can't I return subclass of `X` and inside the angular brackets a subtype of `Y`?

Comment: You can't do in this way. You can't assign a super class to subclass directly. you have to downcast it.

Comment: A method that returns a `List` can return an `ArrayList`, but anything that calls that method only knows that it returns a `List`. That way, if you decide later that the method should return a `LinkedList`, you don't have to make any changes to the code that calls the method.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends. The simplest answer is that you're just going to need to cast the results of `myMethod` to the same type as result. Suppose we take all the generics out of the problem, like this:

```
public class Demo {

    private abstract class AbstractClassA {}
    private class ClassAImpl extends AbstractClassA {}
    private abstract class AbstractClassB {}
    private class ClassBImpl extends AbstractClassB {}

    Demo() {
        ClassAImpl result = myMethod();
    }
    public AbstractClassA myMethod() {
        return new ClassAImpl();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }
}
```

The call to `myMethod` is still a compiler error, because the types don't match. A good way to think about this is to imagine that you don't know anything about the code in the body of `myMethod`. How would you know that it's returning a `ClassAImpl` and not some other subtype of `AbstractClassA`? So to make it work, you'd need to invoke `myMethod` like this:

`ClassAImpl result = (ClassAImpl)myMethod()`

As for the generics bit, you probably want your method signature to be something like:

`public AbstractClassA<? extends AbstractClassB> myMethod()`

but maybe want something like:

`public AbstractClassA<ClassBImpl> myMethod()`

or even:

`public ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl> myMethod()`

All except the last are going to require some explicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

Why on earth would you do something like that anyway?  Methinks either your design is wrong or you are leaving out some important information.  If `myMethod` is in the same class as the attempted call, so that your caller is privy to information about how the method is implemented, you should create a private `myMethodAux` that returns the more specific type.  You are probably still going to run into variance problems, however, as `ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl>` is not a subclass of `AbstractClassA<AbstractClassB>`.  It is a subclass of `AbstractClassA<? extends AbstractClassB>`.

Your comment above seems to indicate that you were not aware of this variance restriction on the subtyping relation in Java.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't assign a super type into sub type without explicit type casting.

Use `instanceof` operator before down casting.

---

Try `Class#isInstance()`

```
abstract class AbstractClassA<T extends AbstractClassB> {}

abstract class AbstractClassB {}

class ClassAImpl<T extends AbstractClassB> extends AbstractClassA<T> {}

class ClassBImpl extends AbstractClassB {}

...

public static AbstractClassA<? extends AbstractClassB> myMethod() {
    return new ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl>();
}

...

AbstractClassA<? extends AbstractClassB> returnValue=myMethod();
if(returnValue.getClass().isInstance(new ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl>())){
    ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl> result=(ClassAImpl<ClassBImpl>)returnValue;
    ...
}
```